# TypeError: Cannot read property 'getState' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, express, react-redux, react-router, react-hooks

I get TypeError: Cannot read property 'getState' of undefined when I run my app, I've attached the source code below:

This is index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import {store} from './redux/store';

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider>
    <React.StrictMode>
      <Router>
        <App />
      </Router>
    </React.StrictMode>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

This is the store.js

```
import {createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware} from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import {composeWithDevTools} from 'redux-devtools-extension';

// Reducers 
import {cartReducer} from './reducers/cartReducers';
import {getProductDetailsReducer, getProductsReducer }from './reducers/productReducers';



const reducer = combineReducers({
    cart: cartReducer,
    getProducts: getProductsReducer,
    getProductDetails: getProductDetailsReducer,
});

const middleware = [thunk];

const store = createStore(
    reducer,
    composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middleware))
);

export {store};
```

This is the output I get
[Type Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ziSfI.png)

I need help fixing this

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass the configured `store` to `Provider` as a prop.

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Router>
        <App />
      </Router>
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: thanks, @Shyam for reaching out, I tried to pass it as a prop but unfortunately I get  the same error

Comment: can you add the code from this file - `import {store} from './redux/store';`